# Which server URL is hit when sending WNS and APNS push notification (PushSharp library)

Tags: c#, asp.net, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp, wns

I am using `PushSharp` library to send push notifications and notifications are working but I do not understand which URL `WNS` and `APNS` are using to send push notification . Can anybody help me to find what `URL` is actually hit to send push notification in case of `WNS(PushSharp.Windows)` and `APNS(PushSharp.Apple)`.

Like `GCM` using following URL to send notification:

```
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

I am looking for the URL that is being used by `WNS` and `APNS` to send push notification.
Thanks.

Comment: You will have to [request a channel uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh868221%28v%3dwin.10%29) and use that.

Comment: @MatJ I am not getting it, any other method?

Comment: Windows does not have a fixed uri it seems, you'll need to request a uri everytime app starts and send that to server and use that uri to send the msg from server to this user.